# How do I delete course enrolments in moodle in bulk?

Tags: php, moodle

Moodle has a built in per course reset ability. I want to reset all my courses.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring this old post back but after a long struggle I finally got that code to work. I've tested it on a Moodle 1.9.7 enviroment

```
<?php
require('../config.php');
require_once('reset_form.php');

$courseids = array(8,9,11);

foreach ($courseids as &$value) {
    $data->MAX_FILE_SIZE = 8097152;
    $data->reset_start_date = 1251781200;
    $data->reset_events = 1;
    $data->reset_logs = 1;
    $data->reset_notes = 1;
    $data->reset_roles = Array(5);
    $data->mform_showadvanced_last = 0;
    $data->reset_roles_local = 1;
    $data->reset_gradebook_grades = 1;
    $data->reset_assignment_submissions = 1;
    $data->reset_forum_all = 1;
    $data->reset_quiz_attempts = 1;
    $data->id = $value;

    require_login($value);      
    require_capability('moodle/course:update', get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $value));

    $status = reset_course_userdata($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figued it out, but be very carful. If you do not know what you are doing do not use this code, you could do a lot of damage to your DB. This does the "default" course reset to all course ids in the array.

```
 <?php
require('../config.php');
require_once('reset_form.php');

$courseids = array(8,9,11);

foreach ($courseids as &$value) {


    $data->MAX_FILE_SIZE = 8097152;
    $data->reset_start_date = 1251781200;
    $data->reset_events = 1;
    $data->reset_logs = 1;
    $data->reset_notes = 1;
    $data->reset_roles = Array(5);
    $data->mform_showadvanced_last = 0;
    $data->reset_roles_local = 1;
    $data->reset_gradebook_grades = 1;
    $data->reset_assignment_submissions = 1;
    $data->reset_forum_all = 1;
    $data->id = $value;

    $status = reset_course_userdata($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not reset courses this way, its too risky.  Use the Course administration feature  Choose the course, find the course admin. block, click the reset button, very simple.  If you have only 3 courses, this takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but what if you have 368? We often want to remove all students from all courses at the end of the school year.